# Why is my Django model missing the values attribute?

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to filter a model by its latest entry and grab all of its values in one fell swoop with `.values()`. However, the issue is that it doesn't contain the values attributes. I want the values attribute so I can easily serialize the model object's data. Technically speaking, I do have access to my fields directly (i.e., `ticket_number.first_name`), but this would require me to manually process each field one by one.

I've used `.filter()` several times on previous models that do contain `.values()`, so why doesn't this specific filter query contain the values attribute? I'm not understanding where or how this query is any different.

**views.py:**

```py
ticket_number = TicketForm.objects.filter(customer_name="Bob").latest('ticket_number')
# The values attribute doesn't exist here, but at least I can access my fields directly.
# Ticket number is the primary key for this TicketForm model.

>>> print(ticket_number)
12345
>>> print(type(ticket_number))
<class 'log.models.TicketForm'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.latest(…)` returns a `TicketForm` *object*, not a `QuerySet`, and an object indeed has no [**`.values(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values), since then the data is already loaded, anfd already wrapped in a `TicketForm` object. `.values(…)` is thus something that is defined on a *`QuerySet`*, not a model object.

You can however alter the order of the `QuerySet` functions, for example:

```
ticket_number = TicketForm.objects.filter(
    customer_name='Bob'
).values().latest('ticket_number')
```

This will then return a dictionary for the latest `TicketForm` record (ordered by `ticket_number`).

Comment: Incredibly helpful and answered exactly what I needed. It helped me really drive home the difference between a `QuerySet`, and a model's object, and exactly why `Object` doesn't contain `values`. This cleared it up for me, so thanks a ton.